# How to trigger alert function on button press?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function that triggers an alert at a given time:

```js
function breakTime() { // <<< do not edit or remove this line!
  /* Set Break Hour in 24hr Notation */
  var breakHour = 11
  /* Set Break Minute */
  var breakMinute = 47
  /* Set Break Message */
  var breakMessage = "Reports! Take Your Break!"
  ///////////////////No Need to Edit//////////////
  var theDate = new Date()
  if (Math.abs(theDate.getHours()) == breakHour && Math.abs(theDate.getMinutes()) == breakMinute) {
    this.focus();
    clearInterval(breakInt)
    alert(breakMessage)
  }
}
var breakInt = setInterval("breakTime()", 1000)
```

I want to assign this function to a button, so when the button is pressed, at an interval of 10 seconds after button press, the alert shows up to everyone that has access to the page. Is there any way to do it?

Note: the pop up alert is triggered without the button, but every one of my attempts to make a button that triggers the function doesn't trigger the pop up on every one's PC.

Comment: `alert shows up to everyone that has access to the page` - you should use server side data, and a loop(or timer) that will check for that server data from every user, and then create `if` data is pressed `then` display `alert`

Comment: @Nick If we all visit a page, and it has an alert function, set to go off at a specified time, then it will go off on everyones screen, at that time. Why would you need servers?

Comment: @nick misunderstood the question, I see, he wants to push a button and have it run an function on every page that is open.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign function on button click like

```
<input id='btn' type='button' onclick='breakTime();' >Click</input>
```

OR You can fire event on click

```
<input id='btn' type='button'  >Click</input>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btn').onclick(funcion(){
            breakTime();
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Thats a bit pedantic considering OP didn't state that jQuery was out of the question. It's still a valid contribution if people are willing to add an extra library. If they're not, maybe someone will post a better vanilla answer. (Edit: was talking to someone who deleted their comment)

Answer (score 1):

using just javascript:

```
<button id='buttonID'>Click Me</button>

function test() {
    alert('break time!');
}

document.getElementById('buttonID').onclick = test; 
// no () on test, otherwise it runs immediately.
```

https://jsfiddle.net/axq0ks6b/

HOWEVER this will only work locally on your page. If you want to press a button and send a prompt to everyone who has the page open, then you will need to set up server side scripts.